# Make scrollbar float over the page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am rephrasing this post to make more sense:
The background of my page has an image and I am trying to hide the track of the scrollbar. however, when I set the background color to transparent it leaves a White gap where the track used to be. this is because the scrollbar takes up space on the page and you cannot put anything under it. I set the position of the scrollbar to absolute but that Property does not apply to this element.

Comment: sorry the link is not working https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU20A.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot get this to work with the rebuild scrollbar, I might have to build one with js.

EDIT:

I was trying to do this again recently and found a solution if you set `overflow-y: overlay;` the scrollbar will overlay on-top of the content. this makes the scrollbar thumb appear to float over the page if the track is transparent.

Comment: This worked really well until recently.  "overlay" was a non-standard Chrome only setting that they'd been trying to deprecate since 2009 and they just recently pushed a new version of Chrome that no longer supports it.  Which sucks #VivaLaOverlay

Comment: Worked up to Chrome 113, doesn't cut it anymore: https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay

Answer (score 1):

You can set `background-color: #000;` for your `html` page. It will remove the white corners for scroll.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: #000;
            color: aliceblue;
            margin: auto;
            background-image: url('https://www.ledr.com/colours/black.jpg')
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 20px;
        }

        /* Track */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        /* Handle */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: lightgreen;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        /* Handle on hover */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background-color: green;
            background-size: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that does not fix it as I am using an image the black is just a placeholder Image

Comment: Can you share your full code in this case? with the real image? (the code from the question looks incomplete btw)